# Genetic Algorithm for itinerary proposal

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I'm planning to work on a project that generates itineraries for user based on provided criteria. User would be asked to choose criteria like point of interests (museum, sight seeing,..) and number of days, budget limit etc. I was wondering if genetic algorithm is suitable for this kind of project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the type of itinerary you describe is actually a bin-packing problem. On the other hand, unless you have an insanely large amount of options, a GA is highly likely to be needlessly inefficient. Instead, you should probably use a pseudo-polynomial algorithm, such as described in Chapter 8 of [Approximation Algorithms, Vazirani](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540653678).

Answer (score 0):

How would you measure fitness?   Is the user going to provide feedback on the "goodness" of the criteria?  If so, it's not good for a GA.

Usually with GAs, there would be populations of combinations of days, budget, poi, etc.  Each of these combinations should be able to be measured (fitness) to see how good it is.  The computer should be able to assign a fitness number to each of these combinations.  So you would need to have an algorithm that can determine how good the the combination is.
After that, you breed a new population and continue x iterations or until some fitness threshold is met.

Comment: I'm thinking along the lines of having a bit string to represent each city, and each bit would represent user provided criteria. For instance City A would be represented as 1011111 where the first bit is for the presence of museum, the second bit is for hiking trails and the third bit for minimum budget requirement of 1000$, etc. As you can see, data does not encode detail info. It just tells you if poi exists in that particular city. Anyway, I'm fairly new to GA so I appreciate very much of your input.

Comment: So how are you going to measure fitness?

Comment: that I'm not really sure. Any suggestion?